# Apple App Loader/iTunes Connect Problem ("Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect")

Tags: xcode, ios4, itunes

I recently signed up for apple's iOS dev program. The account is activated and ready. However when I try to upload an app, I go to iTunes connect, and it says:

"Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect."

and in app loader, it says:

> Unable to find registered user with username "user@domain.com" (1001)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error. It turned out that the username field supports more than 1 string and although it showed me only the correct username, there was the second hidden line. So, make sure your entered username has only 1 string.

Answer (score 3):

It is something wrong on Apple's end. Try waiting 24 hours, it may take some time for their systems to update. If it still doesn't work, contact Apple. They'll be able to easily fix everything for you.

Comment: thanks! i just wanted to make sure! appreciate it! have a great night !

Comment: I have the same problem with a new account i opened for a customer, sent them a few tech support requests, but no answer yet. What's suspicious, they didn't charge yet my credit card, but they opened for me the entire dev center except the iTunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

Just re-write your user name and password at the dialogue where you are getting error in XCode while uploading, and uncheck the checkbox of remember password.

Answer (score 0):

You get this message if you only have a Development certificate. You need a Distribution certificate.