# Cannot log into iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

I have developed an app. It works like its supposed to be in simulator and also on iPhone (under developer profile). Now we want to distribute it. We are a company registered Enterprise program (299$) plan. So i created an ad-hoc profile. I downloaded the certificate and see it in the Organizer. Now I code sign the app with this certificate.Then i build an archive. So i have two steps more. Validate and distribute. I am stuck at validate. I try to validate but it gives me an error saying "Unable to find registered user with username xyz@abc.com". What is going wrong? Has anyone faced this issue. Please help me. Also ask me questions so that i will know if i am doing anything wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Plz try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171618/apple-app-loader-itunes-connect-problem

Comment: or look here, since this is almost the exact same question (compare the text) asked almost a year ago. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1498262

Answer (score 2):

With an Enterprise program you can not distribute your app via iTunesConnect.
You will have to create an inhouse profile and host the app your self on a secured server.

Comment: @rckoenesThanks for ur reply. But i need to share our app.ipa file with tester. I have added his device UDID to provisioning profile. In case of enterprise, which server will be secure ?

Comment: You can host the AdHoc file any way you want, [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) offers a great platform for this. They can handle both AdHoc and InHouse distribution.

Comment: @rckoenesOk, so without TestFlight or any other server, it can't be possible to share an ipa file.

Comment: Using same Apple Id and password, i am able to connect with iTunes connect, but it is showing incorrect during validation in Xcode.

Comment: @AnandGautam your could just mail the created ipa to the user, they can than install it via iTunes. App validation is only available for AppStore app. Since you app will not be in the AppStore there is nothing to validate.

Comment: @rckoenesThanks, i have created ipa for tester. If i will send directly ipa file through mail, then Will app can install via iTunes on device ? or i need to send him mobileprovision certificate also.

Comment: If you build with the Xcode 4 or higher the profile should be embedded in the ipa. I would really suggest that you use [TestFLight](http://testflightapp.com/) as this will make the installation much easier for the user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41964/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-rckoenes)

Comment: I've solved this problem, If your developer account does not have permission to access iTunes Connect, it will cause this error!